# What is the `?` is or the `:` at the equation when coding in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have ran into a line of code in the infamous [SevenSwitch](https://github.com/bvogelzang/SevenSwitch) class.

Here is the line...

```
backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = self.isRounded ? frame.size.height * 0.4 : 2
```

I don't understand what the `?` is or the  `:` at the end of the equation. Could someone please explain what these mean and how they are used?

Comment: Set the cornerRadius of the layer of backgroundView to frame.size.height*0.4 if self.isRounded is true otherwise set it to 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operators can be unary, binary, or ternary:

This is Ternary operators operate on three targets. Like C, Swift has only one ternary operator, the ternary conditional operator (a ? b : c).

From Apple Documents [Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

> **Ternary Conditional Operator**
>
> The ternary conditional operator is a special operator with three
>   parts, which takes the form question ? answer1 : answer2. It is a
>   shortcut for evaluating one of two expressions based on whether
>   question is true or false. If question is true, it evaluates answer1
>   and returns its value; otherwise, it evaluates answer2 and returns its
>   value.

As per your question **if `isRound` is true then corner radios is `frame.size.height` else it's 2.**

As like if condition :

```
if(self.isRounded){
    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height * 0.4
}
else{
    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
}
```

Comment: @justColbs Welcome anytime :)

Answer (score 7):

That's the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Basically it's saying "set the corner radius of the background view to 0.4 times the frame's height if rounded, otherwise set the corner radius to 2".

Answer (score 5):

The `?` and `:` are [`ternary operators`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). They are just shorthand for if statements.

An english translation of `var a = b ? c : d` where `b` is a boolean is *set `a` equal to `c` if `b` is true, and to `d` if `b` is false*.

So, for example,

```
backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = self.isRounded ? frame.size.height * 0.4 : 2
```

can be translated into

```
if(self.isRounded){
    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height * 0.4
}
else{
    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
}
```

Comment: Good explanation, answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: @justColbs No problem, you should get into the habit of using ternary operators - its a real time saver